# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(VPSettingsMenuViewController.MenuType, String, String)'

Tags: ios, swift

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(VPSettingsMenuViewController.MenuType, String, String)'

Getting the error above on the code below.

```
private var menuItems: [(MenuType, String, String)] = []
menuItems.append(MenuType.Home, kHOME, "icon-settings-home")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting a pair of round brackets to indicate it's a tuple:

```
menuItems.append((MenuType.Home, kHOME, "icon-settings-home"))
```